# Buttons don't show the right text

Tags: laravel, voyager

It was working fine in local but when uploaded to server, all the buttons is not showing the text, including the create, edit, delete.

I already created the symbolic link to generate the storage folder inside the public.

What can be the solution for this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create the buttons?

Comment: I did not create the buttons, they are the ones that already come on the voyager. I added one more image showing the text bug on the create and delete buttons.

Comment: Show us the console log errors, its most likely not finding the references to these button translations

Comment: The console don't show any errors.

Comment: As far as i can see this problem going, is that it cant find the language files for your page. Generic is your standard name space